# C# - Marshal.Copy : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, access-violation, bmp

**"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

I'm experiencing this error in the **Marshal.Copy** portion of my code. I do believe that my data is not corrupted nor protected.

I was wondering in what case does this occur.
I have a List<> of bitmaps. This only occurs when I process the first index [0].

So here's how I did it :
 - First, I used this code *[This code gets the pixel data of a bitmap]* :

```
        Bitmap tmp_bitmap = BitmapFromFile[0];

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp_bitmap.Width, tmp_bitmap.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            tmp_bitmap.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int length = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

        // Copy bitmap to byte[]
        Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, bytes, 0, length);
        tmp_bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

*It works fine, no errors occur.*

Then, I apply this code *[ This will remove the pixel data line scan padding ]*:

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[bmpData.Width * bmpData.Height * 3];
 for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; ++y) {
 IntPtr mem = (IntPtr)((long)bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride * 3);
 Marshal.Copy(mem, bytes, y * bmpData.Width * 3, bmpData.Width * 3); //This is where the exception is pointed.
 }
```

It gives me that error whenever I'm processing the first image -- second to last, no problem at all.

I hope you can help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are writing back to the `bmpData` *after* you have unlocked it.

Comment: @RogerRowland it is possible that "I apply this code" means "before the `UnlockBits`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be considering 3 times the stride for every row; your code will only work for the first third of the image; after that **you have indeed** gone outside of your allowed range. Basically:

```
bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride * 3
```

looks really dodgy. The "stride" **is** the number of bytes (including padding) used by every line. Typically, that would be just:

```
bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride
```

Comment: Oh you're right! Now my problem is solved. Thank you very much!